# How do I detect user screenshots, without screenshot_callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently run into a problem I tried to detect if a user is taking a screenshot.
So I found this package screenshot_callback, but it didn't work, I used the example file of the package and nothing happened when taking a screenshot. I tried it on my android emulator and on my phone, it didn't work on both of them
So I wrote an issue report on git but no one answered.

So I was wondering is there any way to detect a user screenshot without using this package, I couldn't find any way to do so, but maybe someone else knows the answer.

I use Flutter/Dart.